# Django 'next' redirect for log in and new user

Tags: python, django

I have an e-commerce website where users can view ads without logging in. However when they want to post an ad they are re-directed to the login page, where after successful login they are directed to the 'create ad' page. 
This functionality is working fine. The problem is when user is re-directed to log in page, and she clicks on 'new user' and creates an account, she is not redirected to the 'create ad' page after successful account creation.

My code looks like this so far:

login.html:

```
#login form


<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">   {% csrf_token %}   {% if request.GET.next %}   <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{ request.GET.next }} />   {% endif %}
        <b>Name:</b>
         {{ form.username }}
        <b>Password:</b>
        {{ form.password }}   <input type="submit" value="OK"> </form>
    # button to redirect to new account creation page
 <a href="{% url 'unauth_home_new' %}#section0"><button>New Account</button></a> </div>
```

views.py:

```
def login(request, lang=None, *args,**kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if 'next' in request.POST:
            return redirect(request.POST['next'])
        return redirect("home")
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if lang == 'ur':
                return log_me_in(request=request,template_name='login_ur.html')
            else:
                return log_me_in(request=request,template_name='login.html')
        else:
            if lang == 'ur':
                return log_me_in(request=request,template_name='login_ur.html')
            else:
                return log_me_in(request=request,template_name='login.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to carry the next over the the create account page. After you link to the create user page from login, the next is lost on the link. so pass the next from login to create user page.

You can just tack this on to the link to create a new account. You might need to get it on the server side from the url in django in the login view and send it to the login template so you can add it to the link.